# Py2app App not launching, but app runs when going through MacOS folder

Tags: python-3.x, py2app

I created an app using py2app, it works when I run it through dist/myapp.app/contents/MacOs/myapp. But it does not run if I just double click dist/myapp.app, it says theres an error. This also happened when I ran it in Alias mode. How can I get it to run just from a double click?

Comment: what's the error message ?

Comment: "myapp" Error. Then it prompts me to go to console or temrinate. That's it.

Comment: And console.app has no useful error information?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and found that if you try adding `--emulate-shell-environment` aka run:
`python setup.py py2app --emulate-shell-environment`
then it works with a double click